# Reading data from appsettings.json it does not work

Tags: json, asp.net-core

I'm trying to read from appsetings.json file some data just like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddOptions();
        //sercies.Configure<Models.AppDate>(Configuration);
        services.Configure<Models.AppData>(Configuration.GetSection("AppData"));

        //It does not works
        string option = Configuration.Get<Models.AppData>().AnotherOption;

        //It works
        string anotherOption = Configuration["AppData:AnotherOption"];

        // Add framework services.
        services.AddMvc();
    }
```

With these classes:

```
public class AppData
{
    public Jwt Jwt { get; set; }
    public string AnotherOption { get; set; }
}

public class Jwt
{
    public string Audience { get; set; }
    public string Issuer { get; set; }
}
```

And in appsettings.json:

```
{
"Logging": {
"IncludeScopes": false,
"LogLevel": {
  "Default": "Warning"
}
},
"AppData": {
"Jwt": {
  "Audience": "http://localhost:5000",
  "Issuer": "http://localhost:5000"
},
"AnotherOption": "Not yet"
}
}
```

When i debug, option var it's null. ¿How can i implement this?. Ty

Comment: If I try to get values from AppData class in controllers i can get them but, it's like they are not visible in ConfigureServices Method. Any advice will be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure why the code above doesn't work.
But I know other ways to do it.

`string option = Configuration.GetSection("AppData").Get<Models.AppData>().AnotherOption;`

or

```
string option = ConfigurationBinder.Get<Models.AppData>(Configuration.GetSection("AppData")).AnotherOption;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
```

Below method can access the data from appsettings.json

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var config = Configuration.GetSection("Application").Get<Application>();
}

//Model class
public class Application
{
    public string ServiceUrl { get; set; }
}
```